# ScrollMagic plugin is working, but is not "tying" the animation to the scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, scrollmagic

I am trying to achieve an SVG text scroll with the scrollmagic plugin, one such as this:

http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/advanced/svg_drawing.html

However, when I took the sample code from here and incorperated it into my site, the SVG animation works, but the svg animation happens all at once, instead of being a 1:1 relationship with the scrolling on the window..

I would presume that there must be some sort of scene or controller property that must enable this? Here is the particular code I am using for this, cropped out of my project:

The HTML:

```
<div class="resume-block-3 container">
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="350" height="200">
                <path id="word" style="stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-dasharray: 1009.23px; stroke-dashoffset: 1009.23px;" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" d="M22.328,70.018c9.867-7.4,10.724,20.434,13.014,28.694c-0.08-9.105-1.308-31.463,11.936-31.886
                c11.313-0.361,17.046,19.368,16.367,28.098c-1.432-10.289,6.234-30.682,18.163-25.671c11.505,4.833,8.682,26.772,20.071,31.964
                c13.06,5.953,14.854-8.305,19.734-17.017c7.188-12.836,4.933-15.417,29.6-14.8c-8.954-3.842-37.42,1.728-28.539,20.1
                c5.823,12.045,34.911,12.583,30.018-8.873c-5.385,17.174,24.01,23.104,24.01,9.123c0-9.867,3.816-15.937,16.034-18.5
                c8.359-1.754,18.982,4.754,25.9,9.25c-10.361-4.461-51.941-13.776-37.749,12.357c9.435,17.372,50.559,2.289,33.477-6.063
                c-2.871,19.008,32.415,31.684,30.695,54.439c-2.602,34.423-66.934,24.873-79.302,2.134c-13.11-24.101,38.981-36.781,54.798-40.941
                c8.308-2.185,42.133-12.162,25.88-25.587c-2.779,17.058,19.275,28.688,29.963,12.911c6.862-10.131,6.783-25.284,30.833-19.117
                c-9.404-0.429-32.624-0.188-32.864,18.472c-0.231,17.912,21.001,21.405,40.882,11.951"></path>
                <path id="dot" style="stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-dasharray: 44.2974px; stroke-dashoffset: 44.2974px;" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" d="M247.003,38.567c-7.423,1.437-11.092,9.883-1.737,11.142c14.692,1.978,13.864-13.66,1.12-8.675"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
```

the JS:

```
function pathPrepare ($el) {
        var lineLength = $el[0].getTotalLength();
        $el.css("stroke-dasharray", lineLength);
        $el.css("stroke-dashoffset", lineLength);
    }

    var $word = $("path#word");
    var $dot = $("path#dot");

    // prepare SVG
    pathPrepare($word);
    pathPrepare($dot);

    // init controller
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

var thirdBlockEntrance = new TimelineMax()
        .add(TweenMax.to($word, 0.9, {strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone})) // draw word for 0.9
        .add(TweenMax.to($dot, 0.1, {strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone}))  // draw dot for 0.1
        .add(TweenMax.to("path", 1, {stroke: "#33629c", ease:Linear.easeNone}), 0);         // change color during the whole thing


var tweenScene3 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '.container.resume-block-3',
        offset:200
    })
    .setTween([thirdBlockEntrance])
    .addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller);
```

I will again say that this is cropped out of the bigger project, so if something is missing please ask me first in a comment, and I will update the post.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include a duration in your scene options. This will determine the length of the scrolling process that controls the timeline's progress:

```
     triggerElement: '.container.resume-block-3',
            offset:200,
            duration: 800
```

Comment: Yes it does, sorry for the late response, I had actually figured it out and didnt come back to the post. I will mark this as the answer for anyone else who needs to know, thank you!